# best way to find dll by name on c drive?

Tags: windows

What's the best way to find a dll by name on the C drive?  When I use Windows native search through File Explorer on C:\ I search using the name of a known dll on my computer and the search doesn't find it.

Is there a good 3rd party tool for searching a Windows OS by file name?  SearchMyFiles is a good 3rd party tool for searching for files by containing text but I don't think SearchMyFiles supports searching a file by text.

Comment: Normal search should find DLLs. Make sure you don't have explorer set to hide system files.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a command line method for finding all of the occurrences of the dll on C: drive

```
dir C:\*<dllName> /s
```

Comment: And, if you wish to search for hidden, read-only, or system files, you can use the **/ah** argument for hidden files, **/ar** for read-only files, or **/as** argument for system files. E.g., from c:\ you could use **dir /ah /s somefile.dll** to search all subdirectories for the file somfile.dll that wouldn't otherwise be returned if it had the hidden attribute set.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not familiar with command line, follow these steps:

- Windows key + F
- Type the name of the dll as you remember it (with and without the dll extension) i.e.  `DLLName` and `DLLName.dll`

If you wanna go the **pro** way, go as follows:

- Windows key + R
- Type in `cmd` and hit the `Enter` key
- Run this command:

`dir C:\*DLLName* /s`

- Or try this, if you get too many results:

`dir C:\*DLLName*.dll /s`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*.dll"}`

This will iterate through every item in your C:\ drive recursively and select all files ending with the .dll extension. Since you want to find a specific DLL you can just change "*.dll" to ".dll".

Comment: Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.